`lsof` doesn't display PID that `netstat -pln` shows
I'm new in this community.
I'm trying to kill a PID and list it with lsof -t but with no luck. The lsof -t -i:port doesn't find the PID. But it clearly shows when I run the netstat -pln:
deploy@debian-4gb-nbg1-2:~/apps/ssr/splitfire.ai$ netstat -pln
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1648178/puma 5.6.1
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1446467/puma 5.6.1
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::3003                 :::*                    LISTEN      987025/node
tcp6       0      0 :::3010                 :::*                    LISTEN      1302684/next-server

The command I use to kill a PID kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:3010). Any clue?

have you try with -i6:3010?

Nope, it's still not showing the process. I tried with sudo as well: sudo lsof -t -i6:3010

The lsof -t -i:3010 command may not be returning the correct PID, or it might not be functioning as expected. The output from netstat indicates that the process is listening on tcp6, which signifies an IPv6 connection.
Try running the following command to specifically target IPv6 connections:

sudo lsof -t -i6:3010

Additionally, running the command with sudo is recommended, as permission issues may prevent lsof from accessing process details. Alternatively, instead of using lsof, you can use fuser to identify the process using the specified port.

sudo fuser 3010/tcp

can you post netstat or ss output ?

This sudo fuser 3010/tcp does the trick.

deploy@debian-4gb-nbg1-2:~$ sudo fuser 3010/tcp
3010/tcp:            1302684
